# Detaching MacOS process from its .app instance

Tags: macos, go, cocoa, process

I have an app written in C++ and a launcher written in Go. I'm packaging this in an .app with with the launcher as the main executable under `Contents/MacOS` which then launches the app. It then waits for the app to finish, then waits 10 seconds for any crash reports to be generated, and sends them to my server.

The problem is that in the 10 second delay after, if I try to reopen the app, the previous launcher is still running, so it thinks the app is still running and just "attaches" the app instance/dock icon to that running process, instead of spawning a new instance.

How can I detach the launcher process from the whole .app instance?

Comment: app is not really finished during crash report. Its execution is stopped but the process is there to be analysed for the report. You have to wait for the report to end. The only way to have several instances of the same app is to launch its executable file. How do you "launch" your app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.